# Does WebDriverWait return an element in Java?

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I've been writing tests with **Java**, and I use WebDriverWait like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

And my question comes up because I start to write test with **Python**, I come across WebDriverWait with Python like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

That means, WebDriverWait in Python waits and also returns an element at the same time. Can WebDriverWait in Java do the same, return an element? If it can, I have never known.

Comment: Why didn't you simply test it yourself?

Comment: A simple google search, glance at documentation, or as @LonelyNeuron suggested, just giving it a try would have answered this question nicely. The one word answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits), yes:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if
>   it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait
>   by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it
>   returns successfully. A successful return value for the
>   ExpectedCondition function type is a Boolean value of true, or a
>   non-null object.

Answer (score 2):

### WebDriverWait (Java)

As you mentioned, we initialize the **`WebDriverWait`** as :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

The [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) clearly mentions, this instance of **`WebDriverWait`** waits up to 5 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds.

So we can rewrite the code block as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
element.click();
```

### WebDriverWait (Python)

As you also mentioned, we initialize the **`WebDriverWait`** as :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

Python automatically assigns the data type so we don't need to be explicit.

Hence the initialization of **`WebDriverWait`** both through **`Selenium-Java`** and **`Selenium-Python`** is equivalent.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to initialize it, the question was does `WebDriverWait` return an element... specifically in Java.

Comment: @JeffC Yes that's what I provided in the second code block as `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));` What issue do you exactly see here? Explain the Downvote please.

Comment: I already explained... you answered a question that was NOT asked. Not once did you answer the question that WAS asked. Your reference in the comment above does not answer the question. See Durden's answer for the correct answer.

Comment: @JeffC I am sorry, I think you seriously need to work on your understanding of English as a language. You seem to be messing up proper answers.

Comment: I am a native English speaker... my understanding of English is very good, thank you. Now to your answer... the actual question asked is `Does WebDriverWait return an element in Java?`. Please point me to the answer to that question in your above answer... quote it.

Answer (score 0):

From selenium documentation on waits:

> We pass in the *condition* as a function reference that the *wait* will run repeatedly until its return value is truthy. A “truthful” return value is anything that evaluates to boolean true in the language at hand, such as a string, number, a boolean, an object (including a *WebElement*), or a populated (non-empty) sequence or list. That means an *empty list* evaluates to false. When the condition is truthful and the blocking wait is aborted, the return value from the condition becomes the return value of the wait.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait